# Override/map 3rd party control to my custom control

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, controls

Somewhere I've seen an article that showed how to override or map 3rd party control to my own custom control. But now I can't find that link nowhere in bookmarks and I tried googling without success.

For example, I've a SharePoint and it uses their, say, `DATEPICKER` Control all over the place. But I want to map that class with my own class. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows you how to do it for the PeoplePicker - you could use similar technique for DatePicker.

http://www.usingnat.net/sharepoint/2009/6/2/sharepoint-people-picker-override-validation-logic.html